# Array of structures in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to define

```
Vertex[] total_vertices = new Vertex[no_vertice];
```

in C++. But when compiling I get this:

> :568:8: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token

I need to declare an array of Vertices of size "no_vertice", and then use its "Length" method to get its size. Why is it not working?

Comment: Vertex total_vertices[] = new Vertex[no_vertice];

Comment: ok thx. i got confused here: http://www.dev102.com/2009/01/12/c-tip-how-to-get-array-length/

Comment: oh ok.  will this work? size = sizeof(total_vertices)/sizeof(Vertex) ???

Comment: @Trt Trt: That would work with a static array, not with a dynamic one (allocated with `new`).

Comment: @TrtTrt why are you trying to calculate the size when you have it in `no_vertice`?

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the `[]` only goes after the variable name, not after the type (unlike Java or C#).

But that wouldn't work anyway, because you can't assign a pointer-to-first-element-of-an-array (returned by `new`) to an array. You need to use a pointer:

```
Vertex* total_vertices = new Vertex[no_vertice];
```

And make sure to `delete[]` it after you're done using it.

You say you need to use it's `Length` method, which has two problems:

1. Arrays don't have methods like they do in java; they're just blocks of memory in C++. If you want to use an array-like structure that has member functions, check out `std::vector`
2. You wouldn't need the `Length` method of an array even if they did have one (which they don't) because you already have the size in the variable `no_vertice`.

Answer (score 2):

C++ arrays don't have `length` methods.  You need to look at `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is.

```
Vertex *total_vertices = new Vertex[no_vertice];
```

However, in C++ builtin arrays have no `Length` method. They have no method at all since they are not classes. The "length" of it would be `no_vertice`.

You seem to be talking *Java* or *C#*...

Comment: i am getting this: initializer fails to determine size of ‘total_vertices’

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
std::vector<Vertex> total_vertices(no_vertice);
```

and then use its `size()` method to get the size.

It's best to avoid using `new` directly unless there's no alternative - it's very easy to lose track of the object's ownership and end up with a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should probably do something like

boost::shared_array total_vertices( new Vertex[no_vertices] ); 
or
boost::scoped_array total_vertices( new Vertex[no_vertices] );

that way you don't have to worry about cleaning up after yourself and leaking memory.

http://www.boost.org
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, always use a vector rather than an array if a vector can do what you want. Because a vector provides an easy way and some useful methods (such as the size() you want). The most important thing is that a vector is safer than an array when you subscribe an element in it (vector has a `end()` method to make sure you can't access out of the range of it). So I think you should write this:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<Vertex> total_vertices(no_vertice); //vector is a container so you should declare it with a specified type.
```

You can get more information about `vector` in [the C++ reference of vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

Comment: A `std::vector` is *not* safer than a bare array for subscripting, but `at` does bounds checking: see http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/074.htm.  However, I agree; **always use a vector** (unless you have a really good reason to use an array)!!!  Your English is fine by the way.

Comment: Oh thank you ^_^ I'll check that!But if I use an iterator rather than subscripting， will it be safer?

Comment: Absolutely...since vectors use random access iterators, you pretty much won't go wrong.  Just make sure that if you loop over other standard containers you check that the iterator `!= iter.end()` instead of `< iter.end()`.

Comment: Oh,I'll remember that but why?Is that for improving efficiency?

Comment: It's because containers aren't necessarily ordered like a vector...I am looking for a good reference.

Comment: @keith.layne :I see,thank you very much.It's a great honor to meet you here.You teach me a lot and I like here more!You're so kind and I wish one day I could learn more about c++ or other computer skill and still be patient and kind like you!^_^